# glCopyTexImage2D error - GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a problem with glCopyTexImage2D - look at this util method which is cutting previously rendered scene to the texture:

```
public static Texture cutRenderToTexture(GL g, int width, int height) { 
    IntBuffer buff = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer(1); 
    g.glGenTextures(1, buff); 
    int tex = buff.get(); 
    g.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex); 
    checkGLError(g); 
    g.glCopyTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, 0, 0, width, height, 0); 
    checkGLError(g); 
    g.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    return TextureIO.newTexture(tex, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, width, height, width, height, false); 
}
```

checkGLError is a simple method which is checking all possible OpenGL errors - in this example I am calling it twice to show that problem can be related only to glCopyTexImage2D call. I am getting GL_INVALID_ENUM error, but target is valid, GL_TEXTURE_2D enabled and OpenGL docs (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) do not specify if this error can happen in any other case.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: In your custom checkGLError method, add a stacktrace to make sure you know where it happens exactly. Use: `Thread.dumpStack()`.

Comment: checkGLError throws GLException if error is detected, so I can confirm that the first checkGLError in above code never throws anything.

Comment: Have you checked width/height values?

Comment: Width/Height values are always bigger than 0, so this should not be a problem. I tested this code with power of two width/height only.

Comment: Hi @Mac70, still need help?